# Pushing data in a JSON object to an array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to use a JSON object as the source for new default values in an array of JSON objects. In my first attempt I did this:

```
var records=
    [{"Key1":"ValueA","Key2":"ValueA","Key3":"ValueA"},
    {"Key1":"ValueB","Key2":"ValueB","Key3":"ValueB"}]

var defaultRecord =
    {"Key1":"DefaultValue1","Key2":"DefaultValue2","Key3":"DefaultValue3"}

pushNewDefaultRecord()
pushNewDefaultRecord()
changeFirstDefaultRecord("NEW VALUE")
showRecord()

function pushNewDefaultRecord(){
    records.push(defaultRecord)
}

function changeFirstDefaultRecord(newValue){
    records[2].Key1 = newValue
    records[2].Key2 = newValue
    records[2].Key3 = newValue
}

function showRecord(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(records))
}
```

This produces the following array:

```
[{"Key1":"ValueA","Key2":"ValueA","Key3":"ValueA"},
{"Key1":"ValueB","Key2":"ValueB","Key3":"ValueB"},
{"Key1":"NEW VALUE","Key2":"NEW VALUE","Key3":"NEW VALUE"},
{"Key1":"NEW VALUE","Key2":"NEW VALUE","Key3":"NEW VALUE"}]
```

I realized that what was being pushed to the records array was not the data in the defaultRecord object but the object itself so that when I updated one record both new records reflected the change.

Changing the pushNewDefaultRecord function to use JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse  works but seems incredibly awkward. Is there a cleaner way to approach this?

```
function pushNewDefaultRecord(){
    var newDefaultRecord = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultRecord))
    records.push(newDefaultRecord)
}
```

Produces:

```
[{"Key1":"ValueA","Key2":"ValueA","Key3":"ValueA"},
{"Key1":"ValueB","Key2":"ValueB","Key3":"ValueB"},
{"Key1":"NEW VALUE","Key2":"NEW VALUE","Key3":"NEW VALUE"},
{"Key1":"DefaultValue1","Key2":"DefaultValue2","Key3":"DefaultValue3"}]
```

Comment: So, what is your question in all of this ?

Comment: Can use a function that returns a new default object each time you need one

Comment: I think you already did that, the second `pushNewDefaultRecord` will create a new default object each time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

With two functions. One creates a new record and one changes values. Something like:

```js
var records = [{
    "Key1": "ValueA",
    "Key2": "ValueA",
    "Key3": "ValueA"
  },
  {
    "Key1": "ValueB",
    "Key2": "ValueB",
    "Key3": "ValueB"
  }
]

var keys = ["Key1", "Key2", "Key3"];

function createRecord(keys, values) {
  return keys.reduce((obj, curr, i) => {
    obj[curr] = values[i];
    return obj;
  }, {})
}

function changeRecord(arr, i, keys, values) {
  keys.forEach((key, j) => {
    arr[i][key] = values[j];
  });
}

function pushRecord(arr, record) {
  arr.push(record);
}

pushRecord(records, createRecord(keys, ["ValueC", "ValueC", "ValueC"]));
pushRecord(records, createRecord(keys, ["ValueD", "ValueD", "ValueD"]));

console.log(records);

changeRecord(records, 2, keys, ["new value", "new value", "new value"]);

console.log(records);
```